# Intellij IDEA: how can I open free form projects in single instance and later reopen whole group?

Tags: intellij-idea

I found NetBeans has a lot of problems nowadays (I reported several bugs) and it is unclear if Netbeans will support Java 9 at all.

I try Intellij IDEA and want to keep several unrelated free form project opened in separate instance (Spring Security sample projects) to study sources.

How can I open it is separate window and how can I **save that project group to open whole projects later in one click**?

I can't get it from:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-a-project-by-importing-existing-sources.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/opening-multiple-projects.html

Comment: Automatic reopening of multiple projects is not implemented yet, only the last one project can be reopened automatically. Related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165545.

Answer (score 0):

If you open a new project while one is already open, IntelliJ will ask you if you want to open it in a new window.

It's harder to solve the reopening problem. You could create a project and a new module for each of the separate projects. I know they're not dependant on one another, but it's convenient to treat them as a unit and that's what a project does.

Using the modular project approach also means that you don't have to open each 'module/project' in a new window -- you'd have them all available in a single place. It's better for searching too -- you can search across the whole project.